# How to perform client side validation using jquery in rails 3 forms

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation, client-side-validation

I want to perform **client side** validation 
**using jquery in rails 3** forms

for the following form

the fields may be email,mobile number,etc

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Contact_number %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :contact_number %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Licence_type %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :licence_type %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

please help me for the above validations

or any other client-side validation you may suggest for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [client_side_validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) gem should help with your issue. It will detect standard rails validators, and apply them in javascript, and allows you to add your own custom validators when necessary.

Disclaimer: I work with bcardarella

Comment: Yes, we are using this on Rails 3.2.7 apps

Comment: You need to use the master branch for Rails 3.2, it is "beta-ish" at the point. Stable but not feature complete for a release candidate. Development has been slow unfortunately, I suspect Rails 4.0 will come out before I ge to release 3.2